# Validation rules for optional fields

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms

How can an input field made with the Orbeon form builder be optional but still have validation rules?
As soon as I add a validation rule, the field is invalid, even though i set it to optional (not required).

Example for a number that should be either empty or between 0 and 100:

```
<fr:number id="control-1-control" bind="control-1-bind"></fr:number>
```

With this binding:

```
<xf:bind id="control-1-bind" ref="control-1" name="control-1"
    type="xf:decimal" constraint=". ge 0 and . le 100"/>
</xf:bind>
```

How can I specifically make this optional? I tried changing my constraint to `. eq '' or . ge 0 and . le 100` but this does not work... What can I do to allow an empty value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree: it would make sense for all optional and empty fields to be consistently valid in all cases. However, in following with the [XForms spec](https://www.w3.org/community/xformsusers/wiki/XForms_2.0), this isn't the case right now. This being said, we have an [RFE for doing this by default in the context of forms created by Form Builder](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3156).

For now you can do it yourself as part of the constraint, by adding:

```
xxf:trim() = '' or (. ge 0 and . le 100)
```